# Character debug in Excel

Tags: excel, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using Excel's Get & Transform to get data from a text file. The problem is that the textfile has special characters and those are not correctly displayed. So I have a sheet with this data, and I have also imported one with the character debug list, which shows e.g. that Ã€ should be À.

The only option I see is "replace values" which requires me to go in manually and change each of the 128 characters. Is there any way to replace all the special characters using the character debug list?

Or any other way to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use a short macro to replace the characters.

Comment: I'm super green to this :) Any suggestions on what kind of macro I can use and how to use it?

Comment: I will post a "demo" macro later today.